# Meaning of left parenthesis notation on chords

Tags: piano, notation, arpeggios, chopin

As an example, in the [Joseffy edition of the Chopin Nocturne op.62 no.1](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/0/01/IMSLP112342-PMLP02310-FChopin_Nocturnes,_Op.62_Joseffy.pdf), there are many instances where a "left parenthesis" is used in front of a chord.  I have always assumed this means a rolled chord, but the usage is inconsistent as oftentimes the same editor uses the standard wavy line.  Am I misinterpreting this?  Is there a distinction to be made in performance?

Example:
[image: Chopin Op. 62, No. 1, mm. 29–32, Joseffy Edition]

Comment: see also: https://music.stackexchange.com/a/115472/54823

Comment: I've always interpreted that notation as indicating _not_ "rolling" the notes, though it was never clear to me (in some of those specific spots) why anyone would get the idea, or feel a need, to roll them in the first place. In the measure-four case, a small hand might need to, but, still, it's a "short tenth"...

Comment: related: _secco_, non-arpeggio, indicated by square bracket. https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109683/

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

The vertical slurs and wavy arpeggio markings both indicate arpeggios.

#### Summary

It seems that Chopin's arpeggio notation evolved over time. In the autograph of his Prelude in A minor, [the final chord](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/barview?workid=6355&pageimageid=72605&barid=23) (m. 23) is clearly marked by a wavy line. However, the Nocturne Op. 55 employs a vertical slur for [its final chord](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/barview?workid=6377&pageimageid=71229&barid=99) (m. 99). In the latter case, however, there is no doubt that an arpeggio is intended. Similarly, Op. 62 No. 2 uses vertical slurs.

The available evidence suggests that the Joseffy edition's use of arpeggio (wavy line) marks in mm. 5, 35, and 36 are editorial/proofreading mistakes. For consistency, all should be vertical slurs.

#### The Written Evidence

The below table gives the markings used for chords in measures 4 – 9 of Op. 62 No. 1. Note the overall inconsistency in which marking, or none, is used.

```
Legend

n = no mark
a = arpeggio
s = vertical slur
```

| Edition | m. 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Chopin Variorum Editions** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Stichvorlage autograph 1 | p | n | p | p | p | n |
| Stichvorlage autograph 2 | p | p | p | p | p | n |
| French First Edition | p | p | p | p | p | n |
| French First Edition (Dubois) | p | p | p | p | p | n |
| French First Edition (Franchomme) | p | p | p | p | p | n |
| German First Edition | p | n | p | p | p | n |
| German Second Edition | p | n | p | p | p | n |
| German Second Edition — corrected | p | n | p | p | p | n |
| English First Edition | n | p | p | p | p | n |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Complete Works (German) | a | a | a | a | a | n |
| Kullak | a | a | a | a | a | n |
| Klindworth | n | n | n | a | a | n |
| Mikuli | p | a | p | p | p | n |
| Scholtz | p | p | p | p | p | p |
| Joseffy | p | a | p | p | p | n |
| Cortot | a | a | a | a | a | n |
| Elkier | a | a | a | a | a | n |
| **Personal Editions** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Paderewski(1) | p | p | p | p | p | n |
| Henle Urtext(2) | a | a | a | a | a | n |

(1) The Paderewski edition contains the following note:

> the original editions in this work always use a vertical slur to indicate the arpeggio, and not a wavy line. We have retained this peculiarity.

The edition further notes the German First Edition's bar 5 omission of the arpeggio.

(2) The Henle Urtext, like the Paderewski edition, notes the German First Edition's bar 5 ommission, and includes further reference to the parallel moment in bar 30, which contains an arpeggio (wavy or smooth) mark in all editions.

SOURCES:

- All autographs and first editions come from the [Chopin Variorum Edition](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/).
- All editorial editions, excepting Paderewski and the Henle Urtext, are from [ISMLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Nocturnes,_Op.62_(Chopin,_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)).
- The Paderewski and Henle editions are from my own bookshelves.